# can i add a jquery animation to an updateprogress template?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, animation, updatepanel

right now, im using an UpdateProgress template to show a div with an animated gif indicating that "something" is happening asynchronously. I have the div with the display fixed to the bottom of the screen. Just like the updateprogress control usually works, when an async call is happening, the UpdateProgress control displays. What I want it to do is not just display out of thin air, but use a jQuery animation such as SlideUp as the div displays and maybe even slide out as it is hidden after the async call ends. Now I'm imagining that the control actually shows and hides the div like you would normally do by hand, so there has to be a way to add in the animation. Anyone have any ideas?? TIA

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i'm not asking for code, I'm asking for ideas like the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

updateprogress is triggered when a server-side process is occuring on page, so i think the best way to implement what you want to happen, is by switching to jquery ajax and use beforeSend for showing the div and success for hiding it...